# jquery-ui resizable issues (can't get it to work no matter what I try)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I must be missing something really simple but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Basically on the page I'm working on I've 6 divs with the same class and I need them to be resizable. I couldn't get it to work so I created a simple test page just to see if it would work there with the syntax I'm using.

I've tried to use it inside and outside the document.ready function and none of it worked.

Here's the code for what is loading and the script:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/oam-white.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.0.custom/jquery-ui-1.12.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/oam.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        });
    $(function() {
    $('#test').resizable({
        animate: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/rodcunha/pen/OXaQRz)

Thank you in advance for the help. Rod

Comment: Rod, define resizable? Like they resize based on content? We need more information to help you. Can you share the actual code with the 6 boxes?

Comment: I mean jQueryUI resizable function see here https://jqueryui.com/resizable/

I've added a couple extra divs, the div's don't make any difference really, the simpler it is probably the better no need to over complicate code, if I get it working here and doesn't work in the real example then I'll have to check why but until then keeping it simple is the best I think.

Comment: Your codepen does not seem to call the libraries. Since you have no external libraries loading, no jQuery is being loaded.

Comment: @rodcunha your code is working when jQuery & UI are loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7eycy82e/

Comment: I added them all, wonder why they didn't load. I had the libraries running on my code though and it didn't work but I can see it working on the fiddle now. Thank you Twisty.